# Android Studio's "Profile or Debug APK" shows wrong library sizes and claims they are unstripped when they are not

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk

I recently made a new version of my apk with stripped files and removed `~/ApkProjects/` entirely to be sure I was opening up & attempting to debug the newest version.

However, Android Studio's "Profile or Debug APK" shows wrong library sizes (way too small) in its file browser, and claims they are stripped from symbols when they are not!

For example, this is me examining the `lib/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2.so` in the corresponding `~/Apkprojects/myapp` folder that Android Studio created:

```
$ pwd
/home/jonas/ApkProjects/myapp
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ unzip ../myapp.apk 
Archive:  ../myapp.apk
  inflating: AndroidManifest.xml     
  inflating: META-INF/CERT.RSA       
  inflating: META-INF/CERT.SF        
  inflating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF    
 extracting: assets/private.mp3      
  inflating: classes.dex             
  inflating: lib/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2.so  
  inflating: lib/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2_image.so  
  inflating: lib/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2_mixer.so  
  inflating: lib/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2_ttf.so  
  inflating: lib/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto1.1.so  
  inflating: lib/armeabi-v7a/libffi.so  
  inflating: lib/armeabi-v7a/libfreetype.so  
  inflating: lib/armeabi-v7a/libhidapi.so  
  inflating: lib/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so  
  inflating: lib/armeabi-v7a/libpng16.so  
  inflating: lib/armeabi-v7a/libpython3.7m.so  
  inflating: lib/armeabi-v7a/libsqlite3.so  
  inflating: lib/armeabi-v7a/libssl1.1.so  
 extracting: res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png  
 extracting: res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png  
 extracting: res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png  
 extracting: res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png  
 extracting: res/drawable/icon.png   
 extracting: res/drawable/presplash.jpg  
  inflating: res/layout/chooser_item.xml  
  inflating: res/layout/main.xml     
  inflating: res/layout/project_chooser.xml  
  inflating: res/layout/project_empty.xml  
 extracting: resources.arsc          
$ stat lib/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2.so
  File: lib/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2.so
  Size: 3803132     Blocks: 7432       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 13769903    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   jonas)   Gid: ( 1000/   jonas)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0:c42,c208
Access: 1979-12-31 00:00:00.000000000 +0100
Modify: 1979-12-31 00:00:00.000000000 +0100
Change: 2019-07-13 14:05:20.501729484 +0200
 Birth: -
$ file lib/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=ab7e06780169e2f4ac5dab149ee66d99af91f3f2, with debug_info, not stripped
$
```

As you can see, the library file is reported as **larger than 3mb**, and clearly it is **unstripped / with debugging symbols**.

However, this is what android studio is showing:
[image]

Android Studio clearly has a **different version at less than 2mb**, and also displays a notice that **debugging symbols are missing.** ???

Also, when I right-click the apk in the project files and click `Show in File Manager`, I can see that the `.apk` is **larger than 36mb**, which again is *not the 34mb* that Android Studio is showing in the screenshot above!

So what is going on? Why would Android Studio somehow be making up non-existent versions of the `.so` files that aren't actually contained in the `.apk` like that? It looks like I'd be using an older version of the `.apk`, but I wiped `~/ApkProjects/` entirely and even went into the project folder and extracted the `.apk` copy it created there for itself from there as you can see above, so where on earth is Studio getting its data from if not that `.apk`?